# Keep Session in Laravel 5.4 after Login

Tags: php, laravel

User are signed up in my app With Modal and ajax But I Want Keep session of user How I Can keep session of user?
my Signup code is here:
view.blade.php:

```
 <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="mySignup">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="login-wrap">
                    <div class="form text-center">
                        <input type="text"  id="name"/>
                        <input type="email"  id="email"/>
                        <input type="password"  id="password"/>
                        <button id="SignUp" data-dismiss="modal" 
                      >Signup</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {{csrf_field()}}
            </div>
  </div>
     $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#SignUp').click(function (event) {
            var name = $('#name').val();
            var email = $('#email').val();
            var password =$('#password').val();
            $.post('/register',{
                    'name' : name,
                    'email' :email,
                    'password':password,
                    '_token':$('input[name=_token]').val()

                },
                function (data) {
                    $('#body').load(location.href + '#body')
                });
            console.log(password)
        });
  });
```

Controller code is here:

```
 public function store(request $request){
    $user=new User;
    $user->name=$request->name;
    $user->password=$request->password;
    $user->email=$request->email;
    $user->save();
    auth()->login($user);
    return $request->all();
}
```

Comment: Generally they auto store in: `storage/framework/sessions` upon login. You can change this to the DB via the `.env` file `$user = Auth::user()` not `new user()`

Comment: first you need to authenticate user

Comment: @VivekPatel I Logined user in Controller What's Your mean?

Answer (score 0):

step-1 :    after authentication of user you have to take all the data of user(Auth::User())
step-2 : You have to set a session name.

step 3 :just put the session name and users all data.
please check the below code

```
              $email = $request->input('email');
              $password= $request->input('password');

               if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
                $userdata = Auth::User();      //fetch all data
                $sessionName = 'user';        //assume a session name
                Session::put($sessionName, $userdata);   //put the data and in session
               }
```

Comment: I give this error `undefined Session class` How I can Solved it?

Comment: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;        

  
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;